# parse xml with attributes and values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing, sqlxml

I have a sql query to fetch values from an xml. Below is the structure of xml

```
<workflow>
  <meta name="jira.update.author.name">xyz</meta>
  <meta name="jira.description">Mobility Story Workflow</meta>
  <meta name="jira.updated.date">1284423336959</meta>
    .
    .
</workflow>
```

Query used is

```
SELECT name,descr
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'workflow/meta')
WITH 
 (

name [varchar](255) '@name',
descr [varchar](255) '../meta'

)
```

I need to get a table with results

```
name                         |  descr
-----------------------------------------------------
jira.update.author.name            xyz 
jira.description                   Mobility Story Workflow
jira.updated.date                  1284423336959
```

The select query fetches only xyz in the descr column. Any workaround?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    t.c.value('@name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
    t.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as descr
from @data.nodes('workflow/meta') as t(c)
```